# local postgresql setup problems occurring when running python file

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
File "/Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'APP_SETTINGS'
```

I get this errors when I try to run my app.py, my config.py 
I learning from an online tutorial using flask 
this is the first few lines of codes in my app folder.

```
# import the Flask class from the flask module
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, \
url_for, request, session, flash
from functools import wraps
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy



# create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)

# config
import os
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

# create the sqlalchemy object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# import db schema
from models import *
```

my config.py
    import os

```
# default config
class BaseConfig(object):
DEBUG = False
# shortened for readability
SECRET_KEY = 'secret key'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
DEBUG = True


class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
DEBUG = False
```

I hope someone can help me to identify what I am doing wrong, I am following this online tutorial to learn , so most of the things are there 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Up3p20rgWCw&list=PLLjmbh6XPGK5e0IbpMccp7NmJHnN8O1ng&index=28

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `APP_SETTINGS` environment variable. Define that and you'll be good to go.

```
export APP_SETTINGS=config.DevelopmentConfig
```

I'm not sure where this is first discussed in the tutorial, but you can see it about 4 minutes into the video you linked to when the author discusses adding the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help I guess it worked but later in about 6 minutes of the video the author created a db_create.py and i followed the same example but I am getting a error which says
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_create.py", line 6, in <module>
    db.create_all()
   Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nihit/Desktop/flask-intro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
CAN YOU HELP ME OUT

Comment: How did you install Postgres?

Comment: i am using the postgre app that was told in the tutorial

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO about this error. They all suggest that `psycopg2` needs to be installed again using the newer version of `openssl`. Some folks suggest environment variables. Others suggest using symlinks. If none of those work for you, you should ask this as a new question so people can answer it.

Comment: I found out a post which helped me out, Thanks for your help , appreciate it